# Why this line stops Sphinx search?

Tags: sphinx

I use sanitizing from example: [Barryhunter's](http://www.nearby.org.uk/sphinx/search-example5-withcomments.phps)

But when I use the line:

```
$q = preg_replace('/[^\w~\|\(\)\^\$\?"\/=-]+/',' ',trim(strtolower($q)));
```

then Russian search don't works! Only English.

What the reason? How I should use sanitizing?

This is my piece:

```
<HTML>
<BODY>

<form action="" method="get">
<input name="q" size="40" value="<?php echo @$_GET['q']; ?>" />
<input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>

<?php
require ( 'sphinxapi.php' );
$sphinx = new SphinxClient;
$sphinx->SetServer('ununtu', 9312);
$sphinx->open();
$sphinx->SetMatchMode (SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED);

$sphinx->setFieldWeights(array(
    'title' => 10,
    'content' => 5
));

$sphinx->SetRankingMode(PH_RANK_WORDCOUNT);
$sphinx->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_RELEVANCE);
$sphinx->setLimits(0, 10, 200); 
$sphinx->resetFilters();
$q = isset($_GET['q'])?$_GET['q']:'';
$q = preg_replace('/ OR /',' | ',$q);
// $q = preg_replace('/[^\w~\|\(\)\^\$\?"\/=-]+/',' ',trim(strtolower($q)));

if(isset($_GET['q']) and strlen($_GET['q']) > 1)
{
    $result = $sphinx->query($sphinx->escapeString($q), '*');
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input string is utf-encoded you use non-unicode preg_replace. Add 'u' in the end, e.g.:

```
$q = preg_replace('/[^\w~\|\(\)\^\$\?"\/=-]+/u',' ',trim(strtolower($q)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifically that regex is stripping anything that is not a 'word' char, or a predefined list of syntax/punctuation chars.

The PREG definition of word (the \w ) is

> A "word" character is any letter or digit or the underscore character,
>   that is, any character which can be part of a Perl "word". The
>   definition of letters and digits is controlled by PCRE's character
>   tables, and may vary if locale-specific matching is taking place. For
>   example, in the "fr" (French) locale, some character codes greater
>   than 128 are used for accented letters, and these are matched by \w.

http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php

So possibly in English locale (or other western European for example), hence many Russian chars are not considered a word char, and stripped.

(if your pages are in UTF8, then may also need the /u as mentioned by other answer)